# How to scroll down and highlight a listbox item when item.text is in string

Tags: c#, windows, forms, listbox

I have a listBoxTxt populated with many items. In another listBoxSearch I select an item and get the item.text to a string. I want to use the content of the string to navigate and scroll down and highlight the line in listBoxTxt that has the same item.text as given by the string from listBoxSearch.

Comment: Please add the UI technology use are using. ASP.Net, Winforms, WPF...?

Comment: I use Windows Forms.